# Cannot open new tab in the same context in Playwright (c#)

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-sharp, playwright-dotnet

I'm trying to open new tab in the same browser session and switch context to it.

When I do it with following code:

```
await BrowserSession.Browser.Contexts[0].NewPageAsync();
```

I got the error: `Please use Browser.NewContextAsync()`

---

```
await BrowserSession.Browser.NewPageAsync();
```

from other hand create new BrowserContext and open new page in separate window (not new tab).

Answer (score 0):

Playwright's documentation states:

> **Page** provides methods to interact with a **single tab** in a Browser... **One Browser instance might have multiple Page instances.**

https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-page

Using the above you should be able to open another tab using something like this:

```cs
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await using var browser = await playwright.Webkit.LaunchAsync();

var tabOne = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await tabOne.GotoAsync("https://www.theverge.com");

var tabTwo = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await tabTwo.GotoAsync("https://www.google.com");
```